# Get frame count left to play in ALSA

Tags: c++, linux, audio, alsa

So, on Windows, I have written a VOIP program that uses the Windows Multimedia System (MMSystem) and records PCM audio from the microphone in small chunks (each ~30 ms long) sends this data to another user and then playbacks it to the speakers.
Now, I want to make the same program on Linux using ALSA and it seems like it's not that straightforward as MMSystem. The recording part was easy but the playback has some silence gaps between chunks of audio. You see, in MMSystem the workflow was simple:

- add buffer # 1,
- add buffer # 2,
- play buffer # 1,
- play buffer # 2,
- wait until buffer #1 finished,
- add buffer # 1,
- play buffer # 1,
- wait until buffer # 2 finished and etc.

but ALSA doesn't have this "wait until buffer # n finished" so I thought I can add 2000 frames, play, and see how many frames there are left to play? And if one buffer is 1000 frames, for example, I can wait until there are <1000 frames left to play and add another 1000 frames and etc.
So, how can I implement similar to MMSystem workflow in ALSA?

Comment: Voting-to-close because ***"Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more"***.... StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The MMSystem API was designed for ISA sound cards (where DMA buffers were managed entirely by the CPU). PCI sound cards generally use a single, fixed-size ring buffer, and this is what the [Windows audio APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/audioclient/nf-audioclient-iaudioclient-getbuffersize) since Vista, and ALSA, expose.

You have to configure the buffer to be large enough that several of your chunks fit into it.

It is not possible to get notifications after an arbitrary amount of samples. The hardware sends a notification at the end of each period, so you should configure the period size to be small enough.

It might be easier to use the PulseAudio API.